# Sitecore User Group Deutschland - January 18, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

## Event details:

- Starts: Wed, 18 Jan 2017, 01:00 PM (CET) (12:00PM UTC)
- Ends: Wed, 18 Jan 2017, 05:30 PM (CET) (16:30PM UTC)
- Registration deadline: Wed, 18 Jan 2017, 10:00 AM (CET) (9:00AM UTC)

## Location:

```
CELUM Deutschland GmbH
Luise-Ullrich-Straße 20
80636 München
Germany
```

## Event Details

- Register here: https://www.xing.com/events/sitecore-usergroup-deutschland-munchen-1757646

## Agenda

Wir haben auch dieses Mal ein paar tolle Sprecher und ich freue mich auf die Vorträge:

- Besser, schneller, effektiver – Wie Sie mit Digital Asset Management Ihre Geschäftsprozesse optimieren (und das Sitecore Data Exchange Framework) - Gerd Laski & Michael Sahlender, Celum & Friederike Heinze, comspace
- Sitecore und Salesforce - Maksym Ponomarenko, netzkern AG
- Getting Started with Unicorn Item Syncronization - Christian Handel, ecx.io
- An awesome presentation about the Rules Engine - Mark Cassidy, CassidyConsult
- Build a very simple Website mit Demo Sitecore Experience Accelerator - Chris Wojciech, netzkern